# What defines when truncation should occur on an infinite binary number (0.1) to represent it in a scientific notation

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand how an infinite binary number, for example `0.1`, can be represented in a scientific notation and eventually in a floating point. There are many examples over the web that explain how the number from the scientific notation can be represented in a binary floating point form, but my question is specifically about representing an infinite binary number in a scientific notation. What I don't understand is that since `0.1` can't be finitely represented in binary, what determines when truncation should be done?

For example, if we truncate infinite representation of `0.1` to 62 bits:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

the scientific form will be:

`1.1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110 x` 2<sup>-4</sup>

So from here if we want to represent the number as `64 bit double precision floating point`, we can calculate the exponent as `-4 + 1023 = 1019` and represent the number as:

```
0 1111111011 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001
```

<sub>*when converting from the scientific form I truncated the mantissa to 52 bits.</sub>

In the example above, I decided to truncate to 62 bits. But I can truncate to less or more bits - how's is decided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should be rounding, not truncating. You round (to "nearest even") to the number of bits in your floating-point format. Double-precision has 53 bits, so round to 53 bits. For 0.1 you get

1.100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101 * 2^-4

In IEEE format, that is

0 01111111011 1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010

(Values courtesy of my [decimal to floating-point converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).)

Comment: thanks, can you please elaborate a bit on how the rounding occur? I can't seem to find a good resource explaining that.

Comment: Also what determines the number of bits after which the rounding should occur? Is it the number of bits a mantissa can have, for example, for single precision floating point I'd have to round after 23 bits? And do you include the integer part when calculating the number of bits?

Comment: I've also read that there are guard, round and sticky bits used during rounding, can you please tell me where they are in the binary representation of 0.1?

Comment: There are many resources on the Web you can look at, starting with Wikipedia, and this article in particular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point . Also remember that the significand (what you are calling "mantissa") is 53 bits in double-precision and 24 bits in single-precision (you are not accounting for the hidden bit). To round in double-precision, for example, look at bits 54 and beyond to see if that is <, >, or = to half the value of bit 53. (Yes integer part counts towards bit count.)

Comment: thanks, I've created [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111324/how-do-i-round-this-binary-number-to-the-nearest-even) based on your answer in this question. Take a look please if you have time.

Comment: you wrote _to the nearst even_, but it's actually _to the nearst OR even_, according to this [article](http://linuxsupportline.com/~billm/rounding.html). Is it correct?

Comment: By "nearest even" I mean that when two are equally near, pick the one that rounds to the even significand (i.e., the one that ends in '0'). If you want the official term, I think it's "roundTiesToEven" (according to the 2008 spec). It looks like "nearest or even" is that author's shorthand for the same thing.