# How do I round this binary number to the nearest even

Tags: binary, floating-point, rounding

I have this binary representation of `0.1`:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

I need to round it to the nearest even to be able to store it in the double precision floating point. I can't seem to understand how to do that. Most tutorials talk about guard, round and sticky bits - where are they in this representation?

Also I've found the following explanation:

> Let’s see what 0.1 looks like in double-precision. First, let’s write
>   it in binary, truncated to 57 significant bits:

```
0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001…
```

> Bits 54 and beyond total to greater than half the value of bit
>   position 53, so this rounds up to

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

This one doesn't talk about GRS bits, why? Aren't they always required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you quote is from my article [Why 0.1 Does Not Exist In Floating-Point](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) . In that article I am showing how to do the conversion by hand, and the "GRS" bits are an IEEE implementation detail. Even if you are using a computer to do the conversion, you don't have to use IEEE arithmetic ([and you shouldn't if you want to do it correctly](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-to-floating-point-needs-arbitrary-precision/) ), so the GRS bits won't come into play there either. In any case, the GRS bits apply to calculations, not really to the conceptual idea of conversion.

Comment: so how do I round an infinite number without GRS bits?

Comment: I'm also writing an elaborate article right now about why 0.1 + 0.2 doesn't equal 0.3 on medium, do you think you could take a look when it's finished?

Comment: You should take the time do to some research on this topic (my site in particular has many articles on conversion.). Also, what are you really looking for? Do you want to know how to convert by hand? By machine? Do you want to understand how IEEE arithmetic works?

Comment: You might also want to search "0.1 + 0.2 doesn't equal 0.3" before writing your article. (http://0.30000000000000004.com/ is one of many sites that address it).

Comment: I've seen many many websites that talk about that issue, but you see, after reading them I still have to go to stackoverflow and post questions like this one. I will write an article where all these topics will be covered in depth. I've taken a lot of time already to understand this and I'm really close to full understanding, rounding the infinite binary number is the last step :). I've already learnt many topics - converting fractions to binary, how IEEE754 floating points are stored - now only the rounding is left

Comment: What it comes down to is you can read all you want about a topic but you have to write it up yourself to really understand it. (How do you think I ended up with a site full of such articles? :) ).

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm doing, I'm writing it up) Do you have anything about rounding on your website? I'm using your converter by the way, convenient thing

Comment: Re: rounding. I don't have it in one particular article, but rather spread across several. (The second link in my answer has a section on it.)